# How to change timed thread interval from another timer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a problem. I've created two Timer objects, one runs some method every set period of time, and the second one changes that time. The problem is this: when I try to change the interval of the first timer from the second, I don't want to run the first timer when the method changes.

I have the following code, can somebody maybe point me in the right direction?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public void someFun1(Object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start1 " + DateTime.Now);

        }

        public void changeTime1(Object obj)
        {
            someTime1.Change(0, 2000); 
        }

        public static TimerCallback somedel1;
        public static Timer someTime1;

        public static TimerCallback changeTimedel1;
        public static Timer changerTimer1; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pr = new Program();

            somedel1 = new TimerCallback(pr.someFun1);
            someTime1 = new Timer(somedel1, null, Timeout.Infinite, 10000 );


            changeTimedel1 = new TimerCallback(pr.changeTime1);
            changerTimer1 = new Timer(changeTimedel1, null, 0, 10);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate dueTime:

```
 class Program
    {
        static DateTime _lastInvokation;
        static int somedelInterval = 10000;

        public void someFun1(Object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start1 " + DateTime.Now);
            _lastInvokation = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public void changeTime1(Object obj)
        {
            int dueTime = somedelInterval - (int)(DateTime.Now - _lastInvokation).TotalMilliseconds;
            somedelInterval = 2000;
            if (dueTime > 0)
                someTime1.Change(dueTime, somedelInterval);
        }

        public static TimerCallback somedel1;
        public static Timer someTime1;

        public static TimerCallback changeTimedel1;
        public static Timer changerTimer1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pr = new Program();

            somedel1 = new TimerCallback(pr.someFun1);
            someTime1 = new Timer(somedel1, null, Timeout.Infinite, somedelInterval);
            _lastInvokation = DateTime.Now;

            changeTimedel1 = new TimerCallback(pr.changeTime1);
            changerTimer1 = new Timer(changeTimedel1, null, 0, 10);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, do you need to save current state of timer? I've edited my post